# Ant check if remote directory exists

Tags: ant, build-automation

How would I check with `ant` if on a remote a given directory exists? Locally I can do that with the `available` task.

Comment: Do you want to check it on a remote computer? Does this computer have ssh server installed?

Comment: The remote server does have ssh installed. From the build server I want to check that the target machine has an existing folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do somethong on remote computer you must have some way to connect with it. Personally I do it using ssh. With ssh you can do almost everything on a remote computer. Ant has got few tasks for ssh usage, ex `<sshexec/>`, `<sshsesion/>`. If you don't want to use ssh you need to find another way to connect with that computer but from my experience ssh is the best. Just install it on remote computer and thats it. I think that the best for you will be `<sshsession/>` but I haven't used it (I use only `<sshexec/>` because I've got problems with `<sshsession/>`). For example according to documentation this should work:

```
<sshsession host="somehost" username="dude" password="yo" localtunnels="2401:localhost:2401">
    <sequential>
        <available>check availability of the file</available>
    </sequential>
</sshsession>
```